Sufficient conditions for a conditional probability statement
Consider the random variables $Y, X, D, \epsilon_1, \epsilon_0$, where

$X$ has support $\mathcal{X}$,

$D$  is binary,

$(\epsilon_0, \epsilon_1)$ are independent of $X$ and with full support on $\mathbb{R}^2$.


Consider some real-valued functions $g_0(\cdot)$ and $g_1(\cdot)$ and assume that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&Y_0=g_0(X)+\epsilon_0\\
&Y_1=g_1(X)+\epsilon_1\\
&D=1\{Y_1\geq Y_0\}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Also assume that the following limit exists:
$$
c(x)\equiv \lim_{u\rightarrow \infty} \Pr(D=1| X=x, Y_1=u).
$$
Question: I want to show that if
$$
(S) \quad \lim_{u\rightarrow \infty} \Pr(\epsilon_0\leq a+u| \epsilon_1=u)=k>0 \quad \forall a\in \mathbb{R},
$$
then,
$$
c(x)=k>0 \quad \forall x\in \mathcal{X}
$$
My attempts:
$$
\begin{aligned}
  \Pr(D=1| X=x, Y_1=u)=   \Pr(\epsilon_0\leq u-g_0(x)| \epsilon_1+g_1(x)=u).
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, let $a\equiv -g_0(x)$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
(S')\quad   \Pr(D=1| X=x, Y_1=u)=   \Pr(\epsilon_0\leq a+u| \epsilon_1=u-g_1(x)).
\end{aligned}
$$
This is "almost" (S) but the conditioning event is different. Are (S) or (S') wrong?

It seems to me that $c(x) = 1$, as, rewriting slightly, you have $\lim_{u \to \infty}\mathrm{Pr}(Y_0\leq u | X)$, which has to equal 1 for all $X$.

I think you are assuming that $\epsilon_0$ and $\epsilon_1$ are independent, which may not be the case.

Ah yes, so I am.  Thanks for clarifying.
